Cycle decomposition of the power of a cycle
I have a question regarding this Math stack exchange article:
Raising a cycle to a power, cycle decomposition
The author states that
$$
ord(\alpha^s) = \frac{m}{gcd(m,s)}
$$
which makes sense.
But then he concludes from this equality, that the order/length of all cycles in the cycle decomposition of $\alpha^s$ is $\frac{m}{gcd(m,s)}$.
I don´t get how this implication follows, can someone explain?
Unfortunately I don´t have enough reputation to add a comment on the article.

You have to show, separately, that all cycles in $\alpha^s$ have the same length.

@QiaochuYuan How can I show that?

@QiaochuYuan But if one shows, that all cycles have same length one would require, that there are exactly $gcd(m,s)$ cycles in the cycle decomposition of $\alpha^s$ and I don´t know how to show that either.
